# How to draw embeddings chart with "HE" and "SHE" ends?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pca, word-embedding, tsne

I have word embeddings. How to draw a graph like this? I can do dimensionality reduction using PCA, but not sure how to draw a graph like this.

[image]

Comment: It what form is your original data?

Comment: @user2952903 I got this picture from this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.06520v1.pdf .But it doesn't matter, I have plenty of words in my word embeddings. I want to understend how to draw a graph so that "HE" and "SHE" words will be parrallel.

Comment: So you want a program to make 1D plot with words on it?

Comment: @user2952903 to be honest I did not completely understood this chart. And I'm not sure If it is 1D, since Y axis also plays a role here.

Comment: first you have to find some method to assing `x` and `y` to word. if you don't know what to use as `y` then you can't draw it. And when you will have `x,y` then you can use `matplotlib` ([matplotlib.pyplot.text](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html)) or `pillow` ([ImageDraw.text](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/ImageDraw.html#ImageDraw.text))

Comment: My question was if want to MAKE 1D chart, not whether this chart is 1D. It is really hard to do this program if input is a image. You could to use some image processing library to get x-cordinate of words, but it is still very hard.